# Point domain to backup server if main server crashes

Tags: domain, backup

I have a server with system.domainname.com

I have set up a mirrored site, that gets all data copied to it every hour.

So if server1 crasches I could just tell everyone to go to server2 and everything should be fine.

Ideally I should just change the domain so that it points to server2 instead. 
But I know that this could take some time and I would like to have it be instantaneous.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[With a load balancer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29).

For this specific case, you put something up in front of your server (it could be a proper load balancer appliance, like an F5, or just a reverse proxy, or even a router - many Cisco routers have this functionality as well) and configure it such that it doesn't send requests to a host that is down.

How, exactly, you do that depends on which solution you go with, exactly.

Alternately, there are products and services that offer automatic DNS failover (Google it), [but your mileage may vary](https://serverfault.com/q/60553/118258) - DNS isn't really designed to be used this way, so it doesn't really work that well.

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally I should just change the domain so that it points to server2 instead. But I know 
>   that this could take some time and I would like to have it be instantaneous.

30 seocnds too much? That is the TTL on cloudflare.

> How can I do this?

Both serves react to the same IP. This is done using a load balancer. Or it is done using a script checking every second and then reconfiguring the IP's on the servers - which obviously have to be in the same data center and routing for the handover to just work.